# No need to reference to windows.forms assembly?

Tags: c#

The book says about a small Windows.Forms program

> The Windows Forms classes are in the
>   System.Windows.Forms assembly,  which
>   is the System.Windows.Forms.dll file.
>   To compile this program you  need a
>   reference to that assembly.When compiling 
>   on the command line, use the /r switch to specify other assemblies.

But I am able to compile this program from the command line(csc.exe) just fine, without having to reference to any assembly. why is this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`csc` defaults to adding references to a bunch of assemblies. Have a look at `csc.rsp` in the same directory as `csc.exe` (e.g. c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5) to see what's referenced by default.

You can specify your own [response file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a1fs1tb.aspx) with an @ like this:

csc @responses.txt Foo.cs Bar.cs

(This isn't useful very often, admittedly...)

You can also prevent the default response file from being used with the [`/noconfig` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hww4s6c.aspx).

Comment: Jon Skeet is a stackoverflow animal.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is in a config file as a directory to use for default "includes"/references.